# How to perform internationalization of custom date using angularjs in HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, momentjs, angular-moment

Suppose there is a date say

```
<script>
    module.controller("mycontroller", function($scope) {

        $scope.theDate  = new Date();

    });
</script>
```

and in HTML I have written

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{theDate  | date : "fullDate"}}
</div>
```

So this returns date in simple English.

What I need is to get date in country based language like fr, ja, etc. Though I am even using [Angular Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to get 'Time from now' but  I am unable to get date in custom language.

Comment: Have you looked at [Changing locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/)?

Comment: Yes. moment(1316116057189).fromNow() is used to get 'time ago'. And what I want is current date time in specific language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date now, use `moment()`.

To get it in a different language, use `.local('xx')` where `xx` is your language.

Then use `.format()`for however you want it.

**Examples**

```
moment().locale('en').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
// returns "Thursday, September 3rd 2015, 3:13:29 pm"

moment().locale('fr').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
// returns "jeudi, septembre 3 2015, 3:13:41 pm"
```

Comment: And what if I want to convert a specific date say '26 January 2015' to french ?

Comment: And please tell me one thing more.. can we do this in HTML also ?

Comment: If you supply a date to moment, like `moment('2015-01-26')` then it will initialise with your supplied date, rather than the current date/time.  Not sure what you mean by "can we do this in HTML also?".  You should read the [moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) for more.

Comment: ok thanks... I was asking the way we convert a date to specific format as like {{theDate  | date : "fullDate"}} to 'fullDate', 'medium', etc. Can we do translation also in HTML ?